# Why does typescript give type `never` when excluding extended interface

Tags: typescript

I created a function to strip an object of an interface. However Typescript (Version 3.2.2) now claims the type is `never` when it should be a type with property `child`

```
interface Child extends Parent {
    child: string
}

interface Parent {
    parent: string
}

const a: Child = { child: "", parent: "" }

const b = removeParent(a);

function removeParent<T extends Parent>(obj: T) {
    delete obj.parent;
    return obj as Exclude<T, Parent>;
}

// b is now type never...
```

This does work:

```
function removeParent<T extends Parent>(obj: T) {
    delete obj.parent;
    type Without<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
    return obj as Without<T, "parent">;
}
```

However I want a generic solution that doesn't require me writing out the types to exclude.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you do not want `Exclude<T, Parent>`

Exclude is essentially:
`type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T`

and as a result, your return type will return `never` since T extends `Parent` in your usage.

What I think you're really after is:
`Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof Parent>>`

so that you're saying 'pick all properties of T that do not exist int he parent'

```
function removeOneAndTwo<T extends Parent>(obj: T): Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof Parent>> {
  delete obj.one;
  delete obj.two;
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: `Exclude` is really intended for removing branches from a union type. For example `Exclude<string|null|void, null|void>` ⇒ `string`, or for excluding elements from a `keyof` type like in this answer.

Comment: Even better: `Omit<T, keyof Parent>`.